# Bing Maps v8 Microsoft.Maps.AutosuggestManager not returning postalCode

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing-api

I am using Bing Maps v8 SDK in my app and AutosuggestManager module for autocompleting addresses but there is a problem with response where postalCode is undefined (check the image).

[image]

And this is my code for initializing module:

```
function initializeMap() {
  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.AutoSuggest', {
    callback: onLoad,
    errorCallback: onError,
    culture: "en",
    homeRegion: "US",
    credentials: apiKey
  });
}
function onLoad() {
   var options = { maxResults: 5, autoDetectLocation: false };
   var manager = new Microsoft.Maps.AutosuggestManager(options);
   manager.attachAutosuggest('#' + attributes.id, '#' + attributes.parentId, selectedSuggestion);
}


function selectedSuggestion(suggestionResult) {
    console.log(suggestionResult); // Returns an object with postalCode = undefined (response on image)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that occurs for some addresses. The AutoSuggest team is looking into this. The issue is that there are actually three addresses that match this query, all with different zip codes:

1. 210 6th Ave, Pittsburgh, PA 15229
2. 210 6th Ave, Pittsburgh, PA
   15222
3. 210 6th Ave, Pittsburgh, PA 15219